# Navigation View not working properly in SwiftUI on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create an navigation view that works on both iPhone and iPad. Currently I have it working on the iPhone however when running it on the iPad the navigation view doesnt present my main view properly. See below:

[image]

1. This is when I load the app
2. If I press products (top left) it opens up the products tab.
3. When I click on a product it goes to this screen
4. If I click Product 1 (seen on 3rd image) It opens all the details into another navigation bar.

What I am trying to achieve is that image 4 isn't in a navigation tab and instead it is the full screen. I tried removing NavigationView from my code which seems to fix the problem and makes it full screen. However, I then lose the navigation view buttons to allow the user to view other products.

Here is a shortened version my code (without all the text/image details):

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                ProductHeaderView(product: product)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                    Text(product.title)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(product.gradientColors[1])
                    Text(product.headline)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .frame(maxWidth: 640, alignment: .center)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(product.title, displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

EDIT:

Here is the ProductHeaderView.swift code:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: product.gradientColors), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
        TabView{
            ForEach(0..<product.images.count, id: \.self) { item in
            Image(product.images[item])
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .shadow(color: Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.15), radius: 8, x: 6, y: 8)
                .scaleEffect(isAnimatingImage ? 1.0 : 0.6)
            }//: FOR LOOP
        }//: TAB VIEW
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding(.vertical, 0)
    } //: ZSTACK
    .frame(height: 414)
    .onAppear(){
        withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)){
            isAnimatingImage = true
        }
    }
}
```

Example project: https://github.com/spoax94/productsMinimal.git

Comment: It looks like you have another `NavigationView` inside `ProductHeaderView`, but you have to use only one in singe view hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post with my ProductHeaderView, I am not using a NavigationView inside there.

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented there should be only one `NavigationView`, so here fixed `ProductDetailView` with removed redundant `NavigationView`.

Tested with Xcode 12

```
struct ProductDetailView: View {
    
    var product: Product
    var products: [Product] = productData
    
    @State var showingPreview = false
    
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                 VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {

                      ProductHeaderView(product: product)

                      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {

                            Text(product.title)
                                 .font(.largeTitle)
                                 .fontWeight(.heavy)

                            Text(product.headline)
                                 .font(.headline)
                                 .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)

                            Text("Learn More About \(product.title)".uppercased())
                                 .fontWeight(.bold)
                                 .padding(0)

                            Text(product.description)
                                 .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                 .padding(.bottom, 10)

                      }
                      .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                      .frame(maxWidth: 640, alignment: .center)
                 }
                 .navigationBarTitle(product.title, displayMode: .inline)
                 .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Asperi, that didn't fix the problem that I was having, I also had to remove the 2 navigationBar lines at the bottom of the code. Once I removed those as well as the navigationView it fixed everything. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13):

Just add this line as a modifier in your NavigationView:

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: All works well after applying this piece of code. Thanks, Thomas.

Comment: works after adding this line of code

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. I removed the **navigationView** and also the 2 lines

```
.navigationBarTitle(product.title, displayMode: .inline)
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

As this was hiding the navigation buttons at the top of my view.

Answer (score 2):

The code works fine if you add just add the property `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to the `NavigationView.`

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                ProductHeaderView(product: product)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                    Text(product.title)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(product.gradientColors[1])
                    Text(product.headline)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .frame(maxWidth: 640, alignment: .center)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(product.title, displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    } .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    
  }
```